# String similarity function - segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

The following function is to calculate the number characters of all possible suffixes of a string- a[k] that match with the string itself.
e.g. For abaabab, Suffixes : abaabab, baabab, aabab.. and matching characters : 7,0,1 ..

But I get a runtime error with the message - Segmentation fault(core dumped).
Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the code?

//a is a globally declared array of strings and k is the index of current string being processed

```
long long stringSimilarity(string s1,long long c,int k) // k is the index no of the string
{
    string s3=a[k];
    string s2;
    long long i;    
    if(s1.length() == 1)     return c;
    if(s1.length() == 0)     return -1;
    s2=s1.substr(1,s1.length()-1);
    i=0;
    while((s2[i] == s3[i]) && (i<s2.length())) ++i;
    c+=i;
    c=stringSimilarity(s2,c,k);
    return (c);
}
```

// value of a[k].length is added to the returned int value before printing the answer

Comment: `long long`? That return type seems a little...long.

Comment: Along with accessing an uninitialized variable, `s2`, it looks like you don't do a size check on `s3` before you try to access it with `s2[i] == s3[i]`. There is no guarantee that the size of `s3` is greater than or equal to the size of `s2`.

Comment: Size of s2 is always less than s3 because i am decreasing the size by 1 with every recursive call. The string s1 initially is the same as a[k].

Comment: I was solving this question on hackerrank. They need the return type to be of that datatype

Comment: By the way, you have a special case that is not handled: What if the initial call to the function is with an empty string?

Comment: If you want the return type to be large enough, use string::size_type

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : That is what I was trying to point out to him earlier. He is handling one of the base cases in his recursion but not when the string is empty because he never does a size check on `s3`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  I edited the code for that case.Thanks

Comment: Regarding your `substr` call, if you don't provide the second argument it will be until the end of the string, so `s2 = s1.substr(1)` would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

This line is a major problem and leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

```
for(i=1;i<s1.length();++i)  s2[i-1]=s1[i];
```

The reason for that is that `s2` is never initialized, and is empty, so any indexing into it will be out of bounds.

I recommend you use the second alternative in [this list of possible `std::string` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

---

After you edit, you have a problem with this line:

```
while((s2[i] == s3[i]) && (i<s2.length())) ++i;
```

The problem with that line is that you check the index `i` *after* you already used it as index into `s2`, thereby again being out of bounds. You should also check `i` agains the length of `s3`.

Comment: I tried the same code, initializing s2 before copying s1 into it.Still getting the same error

Comment: I initialized it with 'a' throughout.Din't work for that. I have used the substr function now and it's working.

Comment: @user3877627 And I've updated my answer with another couple of problems. :)

Comment: But s2 is a substring of s3 so it would always be smaller than s3, so why do I need to check 'i' against s3, when the condition would be false as soon as its more than length of s2?

Comment: @user3877627 No, `s2` is a substring of `s1`, unless there's something you don't show us (like the actual definition and initialization of `a`).

Comment: a[k] is the first argument passed to the formal parameter s1 i.e the string for which suffixes are being calculated.I thought that was apparent so dint mention it

Comment: Anyways, I am getting the correct answer. Thanks for all the help @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @user3877627 Then I suggest you add a comment about that in the code. If you come back to the code in the future, you might otherwise be just as confused as I was. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most possible culprit is on this line:

```
for(i=1;i<s1.length();++i)  s2[i-1]=s1[i];
```

You are trying to modify symbols of empty string `s2`. 
What you are trying to do can be done by:

```
s2 = s1.substr( 1 );
```

without any loop. If I understand what you are trying to do there correctly.

Comment: Thanks.That solved the problem.I wasn't aware of the substr function

Comment: @user3877627 you should RTFM when using something: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

Comment: sure. i'l put that into practice.